# Does the Great Wizard have to be a wizard?

Tags: character-identification, the-worst-witch

The Great Wizard seems to be the ultimate authority among witches and wizards. He sets the Witch's Code, and seemingly serves as the head (one of the heads?) of the Magic Council. He also appears to be one of the more powerful magic-users around, although it's not clear whether this was the qualification for the position.

Is the position limited to wizards (i.e. men) or is it possible for witches to attain the position?  There was mention of at least one past Great Wizard, the one who created the Mists of Time, but no witches filling the position.